# Jquery submit() for a form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit

Ok so jquery works fine when i try using hide() and stuff like that but when I try using submit() nothing happens!

Would really appreciate if someone helped me with this.

Here is my form:

```
<form class = "form-horizontal" action = "demo.php" method="post" id = "contactform" >
                    <div class = "modal-header">
                        <h4> Sign up for newsletter!</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "modal-body">

                            <div class = "form-group">

                            <label for = "contact-name" class = "col-lg-2" control-label>Name:</label>
                            <div class = "col-lg-10">
                                <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "contact-name" name="contact-name" placeholder = "Full name" value = "">

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label for = "contact-email" class = "col-lg-2" control-label>Email:</label>
                            <div class = "col-lg-10">
                                <input type = "email" class = "form-control" id = "contact-email" name = "contact-email" placeholder = "u@example.com">

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label for = "contact-name" class = "col-lg-2" control-label>Name:</label>
                            <div class = "col-lg-10">
                                <textarea class = "form-control" rows = "8"> </textarea>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "modal-footer"> 
                        <a class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</a>
                        <button class = "btn btn-primary" type = "button" name = "submit" id = "submit" >Submit thiscarp</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And here is my Jquery code

```
        <script type = "text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(
        function(){

            $("button#submit").click(function()
            {
                $("form#contactform").submit();

            });

        });

    </script>
```

Also i have this in my head

```
<head>
    <title> Bootstrap 3 </title>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $("#contactform").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

change to `$("#contactform").submit();` because you used bad selector and also in button selector

Comment: Sry, didn't help :/

The weird thing is that $("#contactform").hide(); works but not $("#contactform").submit();

Thanks for answer anyways

My document is a .php document btw

Comment: is `$("#contactform").hide()` working inside `$("#submit").click(function(){ });`?

Comment: Try to change button tag `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="submit" id="submit">Submit thiscarp</button>` to `<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit thiscarp">` and delete javascript

Comment: Ahh, yea well then it works but i want to use JQuery to validate the form and therefore need Jquery to fire the submit event

Comment: No, I changed `<button>` tag to `<input>` tag with `type="submit"` and then you must delete all javascript, which is connected to this button, because `<input>` tag with `type="submit"` will send all inputs to `demo.php` automatically with method post as is declared in `<form>`

Comment: Yea sure that works, but I don't want it to submit before it has been validated with some JQuery code

Comment: `<input class="btn btn-primary" type="buton" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit thiscarp" onclick="YOUR_FUNCTION();">` try this with own function `onclick` and changed type, but I think, there will be still problem with `action=demo.php` in `<form>`

Comment: Solved it! 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

The button id can't be submit.

I changed

```
<button class = "btn btn-primary" type = "button" name = "submit" id = "submit" >Submit thiscarp</button>
```

to

```
<button class = "btn btn-primary" type = "button" name = "connect" id = "connect" >Submit thiscarp</button>
```